# Scheme Double Duplicate List alternatives

Tags: list, scheme, duplicates, double

In a practice exam that I'm taking, there is a question that asks to create a procedure that takes a list and creates a new list that contains two of each element in the old list while preserving the order. The example they provide:

```
    (double-duplicate (list 1 2 3 4 4 5))
```

produces

```
    (1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5)
```

I managed to find a solution that uses map and flatten:

```
    (define (flatten list)
       (cond ((null? list) '())
             ((list? (car list)) (append (flatten (car list)) (flatten (cdr list))))
             (else (cons (car list) (flatten (cdr list))))))

    (define (double-duplicate ls)
      (define (helper list1 list2)
        (flatten (map list list1 list2)))
      (helper ls ls))
```

while it does work, I do not feel that it is the most effective solution since I am using the form of map that takes 3 parameters and I do not like the idea of having to write a second procedure (flatten) just to get rid of the excess parentheses. Can anyone think of a better way to doing this? I'm a bit lost as to how else I can write it. I appreciate any ideas.

*Note: I am using MIT scheme for all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Racket? If so, you can use `append-map`:

```
(define (double-duplicate lst)
  (append-map (lambda (x) (list x x)) lst))
```

`append-map` is analogous to the likes of Scala's `flatmap`.

It's not hard to write your own version of `append-map` if you need to:

```
(define (append-map func lst)
  (fold-right (lambda (e r)
                (append (func e) r)) '() lst))
```

Comment: But apparently, append-map still works. Didn't even have to define it. Still, thank you for giving the definition. I like seeing how these functions work.

Answer (score 2):

This one is better suited for `accumulate`:

```
(define (double-duplicate lst)
  (accumulate (lambda (e acc)
                (cons e (cons e acc)))
              '()
              lst))
```

Again, assuming that `accumulate` was defined like in your previous question - that is, as a fold to the right.

Comment: indeed, it is using accumulate in the same way! I prefer your procedure to mine, though I'd personally write the lambda as a helper function. quick question though: when you say that accumulate is defined as a fold to the right, what exactly do you mean by that? I'm not all too familiar with the term "fold" in programming

Comment: A `fold` or `accumulate` is a kind of procedure that consumes lists processing each element. It can return a list processed in left-to-right order (a "fold right") or right-to-left order (a "fold left"). Look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) for specific details

Comment: I would say that a fold _from_ the right/left is more accurate. If you picture a piece of paper that you're folding, a right-fold folds from right to left, and left-fold folds from left to right.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I appreciate the input